# Why does MSVS 2010 MFC project depend on vcredist_x86.exe for MSVS 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I have an MFC project in MSVS 2010. When I compile it, MSVS generates manifest file that contains the following lines:

```
<assemblyIdentity publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"
    processorArchitecture="x86" version="9.0.21022.8"
    name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT" type="win32"/>
```

As a result, I get a binary that depends on both vcredist_x86.exe for MSVS 2008 and vcredist_x86.exe for MSVS 2010, though it actually uses only vcredist_x86.exe for MSVS 2010!

I tried to switch off manifest generation in project properties. After it my app started to work with only vcredist_x86.exe for MSVS 2010 installed. But some controls (especially comboboxes) broke and began to be displayed incorrectly. I guess this happens because windows doesn't have the following information from manifest any more:

```
<assemblyIdentity language="*" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
    processorArchitecture="x86" version="6.0.0.0"
    name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" type="win32"/>
```

1. Why does MSVS write a wrong version of CRT in the manifest file?
2. How to fix the problem/make MSVS write the correct version of CRT in the manifest file?

---

I figured it out. I had a reference to libcurl.lib which had a reference to openssl libs compiled in MSVS 2008... After rebuilding libcurl with the proper versions of openssl the reference to crt 9.0 disappeared from the manifest file.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I recall something like this back then. Have you applied the service pack 1?

Comment: You should write a short answer and accept it, instead of editing the answer into your question. This makes it easier for future visitors to discover, that a question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this happens because of the platform toolset in project properties.

Change it to v100 (I suppose now it is set to v90), re-activate manifest generation and embedding (Manifest Tool\Input and Output) and rebuild your project.

Comment: No, it is set to v100!

Comment: Check you sources if they contain a #pragma directive concerning "manifestdependency"

Comment: stdafx.h contains: #pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"") No more entries of "manifestdependency".

Comment: Change "/manifestdependency:\"type= to "\"/manifestdependency:type= and rebuild.

Comment: Didn't help. I still have name='Microsoft.VC90.CRT' version='9.0.21022.8' in the manifest :( Very odd thing. I don't have the slitest idea where MSVS can take the wrong version from. It seems there are no mentionings of crt 9.x in the project. And I didn't even have MSVS 2008 installed.

Comment: Check for *.manifest files in your build area. Delete them and rebuild. Are they recreated ? Also check for RT_MANIFEST in your resource files - what manifest files are they referencing ? 

If all seem proper and this project was converted from VS2008 to VS2010, the only thing I can suggest right now is to create a new VS2010 project from scratch, add all the existing sources to the newly created and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I figured it out. It was my fault after all :( I had a reference to libcurl.lib which had a reference to openssl libs compiled in MSVS 2008... After rebuilding libcurl with the proper versions of openssl the reference to crt 9.0 disappeared from the manifest file. (I tested deploying of my app on virtual machine which didn't have internet connection, so I didn't notice that web requests probably didn't work without vcredist_x86.exe for MSVS 2008 installed.)